# Why does EF not return any results when comparing null variable?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm having an issue selecting data in my data context in Entity Framework and I've narrowed it down to querying for null values. I have a method like this:

```
public void DoStuff(int? someInt)
{
    var someData = dataContext.MyEntities.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == someInt);
    // someData always yields no results if someInt is null, even though
    // there are rows in the table that have null for that column.
}
```

The above method fails if `someInt` is null. But this line works:

```
var someData = dataContext.MyEntities.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == null);
```

Why do I get data in the second one but not the first one?

Comment: Try `someInt.Value`.  a nullable type is not actually null, but it's value is.

Comment: @MystereMan I just tested this. See the comment on the answer by Ryan Bennett. It was a good thought though.

Comment: @MystereMan semantically, it *is* null - and it is not true to say that "it's value is": an empty nullable-T **does not have** a value, so it is meaningless to ponder the nature of this non-existent value

Comment: @MarcGravell - i'm not sure what you mean by "an empty nullable-T".  If you reference .Value of a nullable-t, and it doesn't have one, it returns null.

Comment: @MystereMan No because `.Value` of `int?` is of type `int` which cannot be null.

Comment: @Mystere no it doesn't; it throws an exception. Try it.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Doh! of course, Alex - of course you're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess, then, that it is generating and using a SQL query of the form that expects a non-null value:

```
where x.SomeProperty = @param
```

Instead of the SQL to show the c# null-equality semantic:

```
where x.SomeProperty is null
```

(the key point here being that in c#, null equals null; in ANSI-SQL, null neither equals null nor (confusingly) not-equals null - different syntax is need to test nulls)

I've seen LINQ-to-SQL do the same thing, and agree that it is counter-intuitive. The only suggestion I have is: test the candidate parameter for null yourself and do the constant/literal `== null` test instead. It would also probably be able to do the same by inspecting and expression tree and re-writing it, if you are into expression trees - but special-casing the null is simpler.

Comment: Yeah you probably can't get around a null check on someInt. Agreed

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end my statement looks like `.Where(x => someInt.HasValue ? x.SomeProperty == someInt : x.SomeProperty == null)` and that is working fine :)

Comment: @Alex I'd have done it the other way, personally: `if(foo==null) query = query.Where(x=>x.Foo==null) else query = query.Where(x=>x.Foo==foo)` - but whatever works is good

Comment: @AlexFord - I'd probably do `.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == someInt ?? null)` (i know, a goofy way to use a null coalesce, but it should work I would think)

Comment: Any particular reason? I only prefer mine because it was on one line and wasn't too long.

Comment: @MystereMan Oh, that does look nice. Let me test it.

Comment: @AlexFord - i'm curious to know myself :)

Comment: @MystereMan Had to wrap `someInt ?? null` in parenthesis to get it to run but after that it returned no results. Looks like a no go, though I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. I suspect it's still accomplishing the same end result as Marc describes in the answer. `= @param`

Comment: @AlexFord - Compiler must be optimizing it away.  I think you may be stuck with the conditional

Answer (score 0):

someInt isn't null on its own. someInt.Value would be null.

Comment: I just tested this. `.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == someInt.Value)` still returns no results. `.Where(x => x.SomeProperty.Value == someInt.Value)` also returns no results.

Comment: someInt.Value can not be null, as it is declared to be `int`, which can never be null.

Comment: Learned something today. Thanks